# What format is best for placing an image into Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have an Illustrator document that I need to place an image from Photoshop into.

The original images are in .psd and .eps formats.

What are the best formats to save the original image in to import to Illustrator? I want to use the best format so when I export from Illustrator to the final image I don't lose quality.

For instance, a .jpg if I need a version for the web and a .tiff if I need a version to print.

I used to take the original image in Photoshop and export it to a .tiff and then import that into Illustrator.

Is that the best option to preserve the maximum quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "best format"

You can place PSDs directly in an Illustrator document. Make sure the PSD is in CMYK if the work is for print. There's no need to convert to EPS or any other format, although you can do that if you want. It makes no difference.